# Powershell GUI Toggle Button

Tags: powershell, user-interface, toggle

I want to have a button in my PowerShell GUI, where I can toggle between Dark and Light Mode. This code will be run, when I click the Button.

Info: $isDark is set to 0 as the program starts

```bsh
$func_ToggleDarkMode = {
    
    Write-Host "Current Dark Mode $isDark"

        if($isDark -eq 0) {
            $MainGUI.BackColor = "Gray"
            $isDark = 1

        } elseif($isDark -eq 1) {
            $MainGUI.BackColor = "White"
            $isDark = 0
        
    Write-Host "Dark Mode updated to $isDark"
    
}
```

On the first button press, the interface turns gray. Console says

```
Current Dark Mode is 0
Dark Mode updated to 1
```

However, if I press it again, the interface will not turn white again and the console says

```
Current Dark Mode is 0
Dark Mode updated to 1
```

Hope you can help me, Thanks :)

Comment: Where did you read that this is possible for PS GUI, sounds interesting?

Comment: PowerShell GUI is just normal PowerShell, you can bind any normal PowerShell script to a button like this

Comment: You might need $script:IsDark so you're not using a variable local to the scriptblock.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version complete dependent on the state of the thing you are trying to change.  If this starts in an outside state (say, "Red"), this will track back to one of the controlled states.

```
$func_ToggleDarkMode = {
    $modes = @{Dark = "Grey"; Light = "White"}

    Write-Host "Prior Mode $($modes.keys |? {$modes[$_] -eq $MainGUI.BackColor} )"

    $MainGUI.BackColor = $(if ($MainGUI.BackColor -eq $modes.Dark) { $modes.Light } else { $modes.Dark})

    Write-Host "New Mode $($modes.keys |? {$modes[$_] -eq $MainGUI.BackColor} )"
}
```

Note:  The hash looks up are (in the scheme of things) slow, but so it writing to the host.  Comment out those lines if you are going full rave mode.

Answer (score 0):

<#
Simulating a toogle button with three Windows Forms labels.
Label1 and label2 are on top of label.
Label1 left half and label2 the right.
The toogle button is used in an application where it controls
if the checked boxes in group of checkboxes evaluates as OR or AND.
#>
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$Form             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize  = "1200,800"
$Form.text        = "Vinregister"
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,400)
$label1.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
$label1.BackColor = "lightblue"
$label1.Visible = $true
$label1.Text = "Change"
$Form.Controls.Add($label1)
$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(360,400)
$label2.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
$label2.BackColor = "lightBlue"
$label2.Visible = $false
$label2.Text = "Change"
$Form.Controls.Add($label2)
#$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$label= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310,400)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,22)
$label.BackColor = "green"
$label.Text ="AND        OR"
$Form.Controls.Add($label)
$label1.Add_Click({
Write-Host "State#1"
$label1.Visible = $false
$label2.Visible = $true
# add special code for State#1
})
$label2.Ad    d_Click({
Write-Host "State#2"
$label1.Visible = $true
$label2.Visible = $false
# add special code for State#2
})
$Form.TopMost     = $true
$Form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )
$Form.ShowDialog()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).